# Java socket programming header

Tags: java, sockets, header, file-transfer

I am trying to send a file through a java socket and receive it through another. However, this happens:

Send Content:

/*
This is simply a file to transfer
*/

Received:

so basically I cannot escape the received content on stack overflow. It is basically a bunch of unreadable bytes (about 32 bytes worth) and then the message I sent.

```
OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(os);
oos.writeObject(mybytearray);
oos.flush();
oos.close();
```

And for the client:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("newfile.java");
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
current = bytesRead;
bos.write(mybytearray, 0 , current);
bos.flush();
bos.close();
sock.close();
```

Comment: is this the dump from the sender process or the receiver process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why go through `ObjectOutputStream`? Either use the `OutputStream` directly through the `write` method, or choose for instance `DataOutputStream` if you find it neccessary.

Besides, you should not use the `Reader` classes for transferring binary data. From the api of `Reader`:

> Abstract class for reading **character streams**.

---

A complete "send file over socket" example can be found here:

[Transfer a file via Socket](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java).

Key server-side code:

```
  OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream();
  System.out.println("Sending...");
  os.write(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
  os.flush();
  sock.close();
```

Key client-side code:

```
bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
```

Answer (score 1):

It would help to see the code, but what you've got there looks like basic random data.  Some things to check:

1. What type is the receive buffer?
2. How many characters do you seem to be sending and receiving?
3. Are you sure your print statement on the receive end is pointing at the right place?

Comment: 1. receive buffer is a byte[]
2. I want to send 39 bytes and receive 66
3. I think the receive is pointing to the right place. The file is created, it just has too many 66 bytes instead of 39. I'm not sure if this is what you mean.

Comment: Yup.  Note that you have just about twice as many bytes received as you expect; this should make you wonder about matching types.  Now, consider what ObjectOutputStream actually does: it *encodes* an object so it can be recovered.  When you send your data as an ObjectOutputStream, Java will encode it to be an array.  See http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html

What you're getting is the "serialized" form of a byte array.

Comment: haha thanks, I was so focused on the client code I didn't see i was sending a object output stream.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't make any sense. If you use an ObjectOutputStream you have to use an ObjectInputStream to read it. If you want to use a Reader to read it you have to use a Writer to write it.